# Is there a way to access an array value by index x in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a relatively basic bash script that creates a folder named with a timestamp, adds the name into an array, and then recall that name a few loops later so that the folder can be deleted and replaced with another. The idea is that the script will run every X often, make a backup of something in a timestamped folder, and eventually start clearing out the oldest backup once it reaches a predetermined limit.

The way I'm currently trying to do this is:

```
intervl=2
blimit=10 #Max number of backups to keep before removing oldest at next run
spath="/example/example/example"
opath="/otherexample/otherexample/otherexample"

limitcounter=0
timearray=() #Array for storing the folder names so they can be recalled and overwritten

while [ "$limitcounter" -lt "$blimit" ]; do
  rm -r $opath/$timearray[$limitcounter] 
  timestamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S) #Generate a new timestamp
  timearray[$limitcounter]=$timestamp #Add new timestamp to the array at position limitcounter
  cp -r $spath $opath/$timestamp #Copy the folder and files from save location to folder at position opath/timestamp 
  ((limitcounter+=1)) #Incrementing limitcounter
  sleep $intervl #Wait 1 interval before continuing
done
```

I left it out, but assume there is a larger while loop that eventually resets $limitcounter to 0 and that is working properly.

Comment: There are technical issues with your script, but also the whole approach is flawed.  The script bases its operation on information stored transiently in the shell, but the files it is managing are stored persistently on the filesystem.  What happens, then, when your script dies or is terminated, then a new instance is started?  What happens if some of the backup folders are removed by something other than the script?

Comment: John, Thanks for your input. I appreciate it. Some of the issues are actually because I wasn't clear in my explanation, but some of the things are definitely issues I need to resolve. I think what I'll do is have it either have it clear out the folder of the backups from the last time it was run (starting fresh), or have it create a folder with today's date that it begins doing the work in. The backups are only needed for very short term use, so either of those solutions should be fine for what I need. But thank you for pointing out the other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you need to use curly braces when getting an element from the array; that is, use `${array[index]}` instead of just `$array[index]`. Note that this doesn't apply when assigning to an element; that is, `array[index]=value` is correct, but `{array[index]}=value` will get you an error.

You should also almost always put double-quotes around variable (or array element) expansions, to avoid weird parsing of whitespace or some other characters. With both of these corrections, your `rm` command should look more like this:

```
rm -r "$opath/${timearray[$limitcounter]}"
```

(You could also leave off the `$` in `$limitcounter`, since variables are automatically expanded in arithmetic contexts like the index of a regular array. But that's just a matter of style.)

[shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like these, and I strongly recommend using to sanity-check your scripts.

But I also see what looks like a logic problem in the script: in the beginning, the `timearray` array will be empty, so in that `rm` command the `${timearray[$limitcounter]}` part will expand to the empty string, and it'll execute the equivalent of `rm -r "$opath/"` -- that is, it'll delete the entire output directory!

Without knowing the full script, I don't know if this is sufficient to fix the problem, but the first thing that comes to mind is to use `if [[ -n "${timearray[$limitcounter]}" ]]` to make sure the array element is non-blank before running `rm` based on it.